# How to stop a "mousemove" event after a mouse up?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a swipe slide on `mousedown` event and `mousemove`, but on `mouseup` I want to stop the `mousemove` event.

```
slide.addEventListener("mousedown", e => {
  console.log(e.clientX);
});

slide.addEventListener("mousemove", function move(e) {
  //  do Somthing
});

slide.addEventListener("mouseup", function stop(e) {
  //  stop the mousemove event
});
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think you can block the mouse cursor from moving.

Comment: I don't want to block it from moving, I just want to stop it from excuting the function under mousemove, but anyway thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try adding and removing the listener when you need:

```
function move(e) {
  //  do Somthing
}

slide.addEventListener("mousedown", e => {
  console.log(e.clientX);
  slide.addEventListener("mousemove", move);
});

slide.addEventListener("mouseup", function stop(e) {
  slide.removeEventListener("mousemove", move);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Stopping mousemove is simple, just calling the `slide.removeEventListener("mousemove", "function you're calling under mousemove");`
just call it into the method you want to stop it

Answer (score 0):

Use a flag in the common scope. Set it to `true` in *mousedown* and `false` in *mouseup*. Check it in *mousemove*

```
var pressing = false;

slide.addEventListener("mousedown", e => {
  pressing = true;
});

slide.addEventListener("mousemove", function move(e) {
  if (pressing) {
    // do something only if mouse button is being pressed
  }
});

slide.addEventListener("mouseup", function stop(e) {
  pressing = false;
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Why not just remove the event listener?

```
slide.addEventListener("mouseup", function stop(e) {
  slide.removeEventListener("mousemove", function move(e) {});
});
```

Comment: `slide.removeEventListener("mousemove");` is not valid javascript. `removeEventListener` takes atleast two arguments.